# What is a good practice when using Models and MySQL database?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have these two models:

```
public class FsqmModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Section { get; set; }
    public int IssueNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextReviewDate { get; set; }
    public int UserIDModified { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I currently load the DataGrid:

**ViewModel**

```
public class FsqmVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Data to be used for the DataGrid
    public List<FsqmModel> data { get; private set; }

    // Get the data using MySQL Connection
    public void LoadData()
    {
        string query = "select Id, DocumentReference, DocumentTitle, Path, IssueNumber, IssueDate, NextReviewDate, UserIDModified, Archived from FoodSafetyQualityManual";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            data = conn.Query<FsqmModel>(query).ToList();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public partial class Fsqm : UserControl
{
    public Fsqm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new FsqmVM();
        vm.LoadData();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

**Goal**

I am now aiming to join the `FoodSafetyQualityManual` with `Users` table like so

```
select fs.Id, DocumentReference, DocumentTitle, Path, IssueNumber, IssueDate, NextReviewDate, UserIDModified, u.Username, Archived from FoodSafetyQualityManual fs JOIN Users u on fs.UserIDModified = u.id
```

And now I am thinking to alter the FsqmModel to this:

```
public class FsqmModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Section { get; set; }
    public int IssueNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextReviewDate { get; set; }
    public int UserIDModified { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } --------- New line
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

Is there a way I can avoid creating a new prop in the Fsqm model and use the existing User Model to join them Together.

Comment: Maybe LINQ can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many variations of MVVM and it is hard to conclude an implementation is "good" or "bad." One possible way to implement this:

```
public class FsqmListVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Data to be used for the DataGrid
    public List<FsqmUserViewModel> data { get; private set; }

    // Get the data using MySQL Connection
    public void LoadData()
    {
        string query = "select Id, DocumentReference, DocumentTitle, Path, IssueNumber, IssueDate, NextReviewDate, UserIDModified, Archived from FoodSafetyQualityManual";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            data = conn.Query<FsqmModel>(query).ToList();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class FsqmUserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly FsqmModel _fsqm;
    private readonly UserModel _user;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _fsqm.Id; }
        set { _fsqm.Id = value; }
    }

    //
    // Other properties
    //

    public string Username 
    {
        get { return _user.Username ; }
        set { _user.Username = value; }
    }

    public FsqmUserViewModel(FsqmModel fsqm, UserModel user)
    {
        _fsqm = fsqm;
        _user = user;

        fsqm.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(this, args);
        }
        user.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == nameof(UserModel.Username))
                RaisePropertyChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    // Add RaisePropertyChanged()
}
```

Also make the 2 model classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

This way, you could:

- Keep model classes generic (i.e. it is not written for a particular View or use-case)
- You do not directly expose the model objects
- You can create new view models if you have another View that needs to show another list with "email" property as well.

Keep in mind there are many other possible implementations. Most of the time it's about weighing what is important for your project.